# Error while deploying into main net for icp

Tags: internet-computer

Used dfx deploy --network ic and faced this error
Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
Failed while trying to install all canisters.
Failed to install wasm module to canister 'ICP_Blockbash_frontend'.
Failed to store assets in canister 'ICP_Blockbash_frontend'.
Failed asset sync with canister gvjvv-xqaaa-aaaam-aby2q-cai.
Failed to create batch: The replica returned a replica error: reject code CanisterReject, reject message Caller does not have Prepare permission, error code None

I tried to restart the terminal but the same issue. I have a wallet with 10 trillion cycles